# Recurso do Bootstrap 3 existe?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Existe esse recurso no Bootstrap 3? Não encontrei e acho tão frequente o uso em sites.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem sim jovem e se chama **tabs**, aqui está a documentação oficial do BS3 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
    <div>

        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
      
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">1</div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">2</div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">3</div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">4</div>
        </div>
      
      </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Hugo!

Comment: @EliseuB. Sem problemas 